# Can not remove dynamically added <select> using removeChild

Tags: javascript, html, css, removechild

I'm fairly new to coding web applications and I'm trying to dynamically add and delete dropdowns.

The delete function does not seem to work at all on button press.

I have the following code:

```js
var selectionCounter = 0;

function cloneSelect() {
  var select = document.getElementById("List");
  var clone = select.cloneNode(true);
  var name = select.getAttribute("name") + selectionCounter++;
  clone.id = name;
  clone.setAttribute("name", name);
  document.getElementById("selectContainer").appendChild(clone)
}
function deleteSelect() {                                                          
var select = document.getElementById("roomList");                              
var existingNode = select.cloneNode(true);                                     
var name = select.getAttribute("name") + selectionCounter--;                   
document.getElementById("selectContainer").parentNode.removeChild(existingNode)
}
```

```html
<div id="selectContainer">
  <select id="List" name="List" required>
    <option>Populated by php<option>        
  </select>
</div>
<button onclick="cloneSelect()"  type="submit" class="button">Add Room</button>
<button onclick="deleteSelect()"  type="submit" class="button" >Delete Room</button>
```

Comment: Please finish the snippet I made for you  - create a [mcve] - but yeah - don't delete a clone

Comment: You are cloning the node in your `deleteSelect()`method whereas you need to target the existing node. Show how/when you are using the above methods. complete the snippet created for you by @mplungjan

Comment: I think I've done as asked? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: For sure make your buttons `type="button"` !!!

Comment: why are you cloning a node in the delete function ?

Comment: OOPS! That comes from copying and pasting the overall form's button! How do I access the existing node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make the buttons buttons instead of submit
2. do not delete a clone.

```js
var selectionCounter = 0;

function cloneSelect() {
  var select = document.getElementById("List");
  var clone = select.cloneNode(true);
  var name = select.getAttribute("name") + selectionCounter++;
  clone.id = name;
  clone.setAttribute("name", name);
  document.getElementById("selectContainer").appendChild(clone)
}

function deleteSelect() {
  selectionCounter--;
  var sel = document.getElementById("List"+(selectionCounter));
  if (sel) document.getElementById("selectContainer").removeChild(sel);
}
```

```html
<div id="selectContainer">
  <select id="List" name="List" required>
    <option>Populated by php<option>        
  </select>
</div>
<button onclick="cloneSelect()"  type="button" class="button">Add Room</button>
<button onclick="deleteSelect()"  type="button" class="button" >Delete Room</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning the node in the `deleteSelect()` method whereas you need to target the existing node to be removed.

```
//Create a valid id
var name = select.getAttribute("name") + --selectionCounter;
//Target the element
var clone = document.getElementById(name);
//Remove the element
clone.parentNode.removeChild(clone);
```

Additionally, make your buttons `type="button"`

```js
var selectionCounter = 0;

function cloneSelect() {
  var select = document.getElementById("List");
  var clone = select.cloneNode(true);
  var name = select.getAttribute("name") + selectionCounter++;
  clone.id = name;
  console.log(name)
  clone.setAttribute("name", name);
  document.getElementById("selectContainer").appendChild(clone)
}

function deleteSelect() {
  var select = document.getElementById("List");
  //Create a valid id
  var name = select.getAttribute("name") + --selectionCounter;
  //Target the element
  var clone = document.getElementById(name)
  clone.parentNode.removeChild(clone)
}
```

```html
<div id="selectContainer">
  <select id="List" name="List" required>
    <option>Populated by php<option>        
  </select>
</div>
<button onclick="cloneSelect()"  type="button" class="button">Add Room</button>
<button onclick="deleteSelect()"  type="button" class="button" >Delete Room</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the most recently added `<select>` using `container.lastElementChild` (where `container` refers to your `<div id="selectContainer">` element):

```js
var counter = 0
var container = document.getElementById("selectContainer")
var select = document.getElementById("List")

function cloneSelect() {
  var clone = select.cloneNode(true)
  clone.id = clone.name = (select.name + counter++)
  container.appendChild(clone)
}

function deleteSelect() {
  if (counter) {
    counter--
    container.removeChild(container.lastElementChild)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="selectContainer">
  <select id="List" name="List" required>
    <option>Populated by php<option>        
  </select>
</div>
<button onclick="cloneSelect()" type="submit" class="button">Add Room</button>
<button onclick="deleteSelect()" type="submit" class="button">Delete Room</button>
```